# Build Git on Windows using symbolic links?

Tags: git, makefile, symlink

I successfully built Git on Windows using the source
[github.com/msysgit/git](//github.com/msysgit/git).

When I go into `/libexec/git-core` I see 106 files at 5,329 KB each.

```
git.exe
git-add.exe
git-apply.exe
etc.
```

How do I build Git so that these are proper 0 byte shortcuts?

Comment: Check that they are not hard links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Git with GCC creates several hard links. These appear to each take up 5,329 KB but they are all linked to the same memory, so in total they take up 5,329 KB.

Knowing this I wanted a way to simply build Git without them, so I posted to the mailing list. Here was my response.

> If you really want to do so, the right way is not by mucking BUILT_INS
>   to empty.  I do not know how GfW is built, but if it uses our usual
>   Makefile, find the place where it installs the git-foo forms of links
>   after it installs the main git executable, and comment it out.
>
> And no, it will *not* be a compilation option, as the resulting
>   installation will break the age-old promise we made to script writers.

[thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/196179/focus=196182](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/196179/focus=196182)